# Writing JS to div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a switch case set up in my site, and it works if I use document.write(), however, doing that opens the results in a new screen, and I am wanting it to print the results to the div.  I am not experienced in JS;  I am trying the document.getElementById(), but I don't think I fully grasp the concept of it:

```
<form id="form1">
    <p>Enter 7 digit CPN :  <input name="cpn" type="text" size="20"> (CAPITALIZE all letters)</form>
    <button onclick="outputname()"> Submit</button></p>

    <script>
    function outputname(){
        var x,name,a,b,answer,y;
        x=document.getElementById("form1");
        y=x.elements["cpn"].value;
    switch(y){
        case "LIG007":
            text = "LIG007: Located in the 737 Avionics Cart Drawer 1.  Keyword LIGHT";
            break;

        case "4080703":
            text = "4080703: Located in the 737 Avionics Cart Drawer 1.  Keyword LAMP";
            break;

        case "4089797":
            text = "4089797: Located in the 737 Avionics Cart Drawer 1.  Keywork IDENTIFIER";
            break;

            default:
            text = "CPN NOT FOUND, PLEASE MAKE SURE IT WAS TYPED CORRECTLY.";
    }
        document.getElementById('cpn')innerHTML;
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('cpn')innerHTML;` is a syntax error and you don’t do anything with `text`.

Comment: `document.getElementById('cpn').value=text` after setting an ID to cpn - voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: `).innerHTML = text;`, there should be a period `.` between `)` and `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 2):

You've almost got it. Try;

```
document.getElementById('cpn').innerHTML = text;
```

As a side note, define `var text = ""` outside (above) of your switch statement.

You can find more info about innerHTML at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

***EDIT***

Assuming you're trying to get the value from your input field and use it to figure out what text to put  in your div, you'll need to change the **ID** in the *.innerHTML* to match the ID of your div.

Comment: except there is no such thing as an element with ID=cpn and the name=cpn is an inputfield

Comment: I'm assuming OP didn't give us all his code, but yes, you need to make sure you have a div with that identifier.

Comment: Good point. Yes, @op will. That'll teach me to quickly scan the JS forgetting the html :)

Answer (score 0):

1. if you use getElementById you need an id, not just a name;  I have added a span with another ID for the output
2. form fields have .value not .innerHTML - innerHTML is used for tags like span and p
3. type=button - if inside the form
4. you cannot split a form over container tags

```js
function outputname() {
  var x, name, a, b, answer, y;
  x = document.getElementById("form1");
  y = x.elements["cpn"].value;
  switch (y) {
    case "LIG007":
      text = "LIG007: Located in the 737 Avionics Cart Drawer 1.  Keyword LIGHT";
      break;

    case "4080703":
      text = "4080703: Located in the 737 Avionics Cart Drawer 1.  Keyword LAMP";
      break;

    case "4089797":
      text = "4089797: Located in the 737 Avionics Cart Drawer 1.  Keywork IDENTIFIER";
      break;

    default:
      text = "CPN NOT FOUND, PLEASE MAKE SURE IT WAS TYPED CORRECTLY.";
  }
  document.getElementById('cpnOut').innerHTML=text;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <p>Enter 7 digit CPN : <input id="cpn" name="cpn" type="text" size="20"> (CAPITALIZE all letters)
    <button type="button" onclick="outputname()"> Submit</button></p>
</form>
<span id="cpnOut"></span>
```